# Finding all unifications in prolog

Tags: prolog, unification, prolog-findall

I wrote my first simple code in PROLOG:

```
is_beginning([], _).
is_beginning([FirstLetterB|RestWordB], [FirstLetterW|RestWordW]) :-
   FirstLetterB == FirstLetterW,
   is_beginning(RestWordB, RestWordW).
```

It is designed to find out if first argument of is_beginning is equal to the second one beginning.
Well, IMHO it can answer questions quite well, but now i wonder if there is any possibility of getting all possible answers for defined second argument.
eg. for

```
is_beginning(Answers, [a,b,c]);
```

i wish to get
[], [a], [a,b], [a,b,c]
as Answers unification, but I am getting only [] (simplest answer).

Is there any possibility of getting what I want? Maybe there is something wrong in my definition?
I already tried to use findall and forall, but it doesn't work to well for me :(

Thanks for all answers.

Comment: By the way, you can simplify your second rule a bit. Instead of explicitly writing the equality constraint, you can do it implicitly by reusing the same variable: `is_beginning([X|A],[X|B]):-is_beginning(A,B).`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using ([==](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=%28==%29/2))/2 when non needed (note the comment at end of documentation page). Indeed, if you change it to 'simple' unification (=)/2 your program works as you expect:

```
is_beginning([], _).
is_beginning([FirstLetterB|RestWordB], [FirstLetterW|RestWordW]) :-
    FirstLetterB = FirstLetterW,
    is_beginning(RestWordB, RestWordW).
```

test:

```
?- is_beginning(Answers, [a,b,c]).
Answers = [] ;
Answers = [a] ;
Answers = [a, b] ;
Answers = [a, b, c] ;
false.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - too much C++ :(

Answer (score 1):

The interpreter won't immediately return all solutions. When it returns `[]`, press ";" to tell it to continue searching:

```
?- is_beginning(X, [a,b,c]).
X = [] ;
X = [a] ;
X = [a, b] ;
X = [a, b, c] ;
false.
```

If you need all these solutions in a Prolog list, rather than just printed out in the console, `findall/3` is indeed what you're looking for:

```
?- findall(X, is_beginning(X, [a,b,c]), L).
L = [[], [a], [a, b], [a, b, c]].
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i already tried both of your solution.
It looks like interpreter returns only one answer, but I'm not sure why.

Comment: @Yester Oops... Missed the `==` in your rule. See CapelliC's answer.